# What is the meaning of the second parameter of the alert method?

Tags: javascript, alert

```
alert(number + " times 9 = ", number * 9);
```

I've seen this snippet in online javascript sudying course and I can't understand what is the meaning of the the parameter after the comma (number * 9). Unfortunately I can't find and answer on the web. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) only takes one argument. [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) on the other hand will let you print out multiple things at a time, usually separated with a space, by providing multiple arguments. As for what the second one means, it means "multiply the value in `number` by 9"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) says nothing about a second parameter in alert method.

> **Syntax:** window.alert(*message*);
>
> `message` is an optional string of text you want to display in the alert
>   dialog, or, alternatively, an object that is converted into a string
>   and displayed.

When you pass a second parameter to a function that has only one in its signature, the second parameter will be ignored. However it will be accessible by [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object inside the function.

Example:

```js
var functionWithOnlyOneParameter = function (firstParameter) {
   console.log(firstParameter);
   console.log(arguments[0]); // same as 'firstParameter'
   console.log(arguments[1]);
}

functionWithOnlyOneParameter('first String', 'second String');
```

Comment: You should replace the last `console.log` with a function call... ^^

Answer (score 1):

[`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) only accepts one argument. There is no meaning to passing a second argument. It is simply ignored.

I recommend using a good documentation such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to quickly find answer to such questions on your own.

PS: If you surround the arguments in parentheses, you will get a different result as you now make use of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to evaluate both expressions and pass only the resulting value of the second expression as a single argument:

```js
let number = 1;

alert((number + " times 9 = ", number * 9)); // alert(number * 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can provide as many arguments as you like to a function but they are simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is no second argument for `alert`. I think that comma was meant to be another plus, as in

```
alert(number + " times 9 = " + number * 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, the standard `alert()` function accepts only one parameter.

I suspect that, if you search through the introductory material or footnotes in your online course, you will find that the instructors overrode the default alert function with their own that can accept an arbitrary number of arguments with which to perform string concatenation, similar to the common implementation of `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot say. in most cases ( were alert points to window.alert) id does nothing, but we could do

```
let alert=(...args)=>window.alert(args.join(";"));
```

Now it has a meaning to use multiple params:

```
alert("test","test");
```

Comment: @le_m i admit the let, and also that i always did ... wrong in all of my answers ( :/)

Comment: It helps to be paranoid like me and run all code in the console before posting :/

Comment: @le_m im on mobile. I would if im on desktop :/